# How to see the friend's Skype avatar in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, images, skype, ubuntu-14.04, avatar

I am using Skype on Ubuntu 14.04. I cannot see what is in the avatar image of a friend. Is there a possibility to see it larger?

I have this:

[image: avatars]

And I want to see the images, because I cannot understand exactly what is there. I have seen that for groups, if I stay on the image in the window of texting it gets bigger:

[image: group avatar]

but for users, I cannot do this, because there is no image in the top of the texting window, how to see user's avatar?

Comment: Could you possibly post a screenshot or find a similar image of the problem you have on net ?

Comment: The image in the avatar is very small

Comment: I cannot post image, can you suggest me somewhere to post it, or just upvote until I have 10 reputation... :)

Comment: I suppose it is ok if you upload it somewhere and post the link in a comment.

Comment: yes, but where? Can you suggest something?

Comment: I have added photos